# UITableview with multiple selection?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on multiple selection in **UITableviewCell**,i can doing that,the problem  occurs when selected value is added into array and remove it from array. I have taken selected value from another array.i think, the following scenario i did mistake "i have selected multiple row,then i am deselecting one by one its getting crashing" with following crash 
**-[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'**

I can understand issues but not able to solve,is there anyway to get selected values in array?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [selectedValue addObject:[[listAns valueForKey:@"o_id"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = NO;
    tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [selectedValue removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //[selectedValue removeLastObject];
    tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = YES;
    tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: karthik, if you use **addObject** , you should use **removeObject**, not **removeObjectAtIndex** ,both are different, remove objectatIndex check the index, object check the object

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks.both answer working me

Comment: bro your coding is fine , you made the mistake in single line,just change this line  **[selectedValue removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];** into **[selectedValue removeObject:[[listAns valueForKey:@"o_id"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];**,then surely works

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks anna..i understand problem.thanks for help

Comment: happy to help you ma, try to implennt the optimize the code.. ,

Answer (score 1):

the error says **[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'**, you try to remove the index out of range.your array contains only one value but you try to remove second Index.

do like

create the one common array for comapre the checkmark value in `CellforRowAtIndex`

```
{

NSMutableArray *storeSelectedcell
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    storeSelectedcell = [NSMutableArray array];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // initilize the cell and additional code

    if ([storeSelectedcell containsObject:indexPath])
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    else
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


    return cell;
}


 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Remove the selection
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];



    // allow multiple selection
    if ([storeSelectedcell containsObject:indexPath])
      [storeSelectedcell removeObject:indexPath];
    else
      [storeSelectedcell addObject:indexPath];

    // finally refresh your table
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,have temporary reference in your delegate method and check

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *val =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[listAns valueForKey:@"o_id"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [selectedValue addObject:val];
    tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = NO;
    tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *val =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[listAns valueForKey:@"o_id"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [selectedValue removeObject:val];
    tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = YES;
    tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```