# How to add check box to my UITableView using custom cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableview with custom cell. In that cell i have a button which i have planned to use as a checkbox. It means on clicking the button i change the image to a "tick mark". Again selecting it changes to the empty button. I have done that part, but the problem is since UITablecell reuses the cell the tick appears again for non selected cells if i scroll down. Please help me with a sample code or a logic to implement this. Please note i don't wish to use checkmark accessory which is the default of UITable.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"cells";
    cell = (MyWachizCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.whiteCircle.tag = indexPath.row;
    //cell=nil;
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cellLoadArray=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MyWachizCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

        if(tableView==self.tableMyFavourite)
        {
            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            {
                cell=[cellLoadArray objectAtIndex:3];

            }
            else
            {
                cell=[cellLoadArray objectAtIndex:1];
                NSLog(@"Index Path %ld",(long)indexPath.row);

            }


            if(indexPath.row%2==0)
                cell.imgCellBg.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            else
                cell.imgCellBg.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.91 blue:0.91 alpha:1.0];
        }
        else if (tableView==self.tableMySearch)
        {
            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            {
                cell=[cellLoadArray objectAtIndex:2];

            }
            else
            {
                cell=[cellLoadArray objectAtIndex:0];

            }

            if(indexPath.row%2==0)
                cell.imgCellBg.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            else
                cell.imgCellBg.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.91 blue:0.91 alpha:1.0];
        }
        else if(tableView==self.tableMyAds)
        {
            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            {
                cell=[cellLoadArray objectAtIndex:3];

            }
            else
            {
                cell=[cellLoadArray objectAtIndex:1];

            }
            if(indexPath.row%2==0)
                cell.imgCellBg.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            else
                cell.imgCellBg.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.91 blue:0.91 alpha:1.0];
        }
    }
    cell.btnGreen.hidden=YES;
    cell.btnAdsDeleteAction.hidden=YES;
    self.btnMyFavoriteDeleteCheckBox.hidden=YES;
    self.btnMySearchesDeleteCheckBox.hidden=YES;
    self.btnMyAdsDeleteCheckBox.hidden=YES;
    self.btnMyFavoriteDeleteAction.hidden=YES;
    self.btnMySearchesDeleteAction.hidden=YES;
    self.btnMyAdsDeleteAction.hidden=YES;

    if(tableView==self.tableMyFavourite)
    {
        cell.btnGreen.hidden=NO;
        cell.btnAdsDeleteAction.hidden=YES;
        self.btnMyFavoriteDeleteCheckBox.hidden=NO;
        self.btnMySearchesDeleteCheckBox.hidden=YES;
        self.btnMyAdsDeleteCheckBox.hidden=YES;
        self.btnMyFavoriteDeleteAction.hidden=NO;
        self.btnMySearchesDeleteAction.hidden=YES;
        self.btnMyAdsDeleteAction.hidden=YES;

//        if(checkBoxTagValue==1)
//        {
//            //cell.btnGreen.selected=YES;
//            cell.imgCheckbox.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"markedmw.png"];
//        }
//        else
//        {
//            //cell.btnGreen.selected=NO;
//            cell.imgCheckbox.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"unmarkedmw.png"];
//        }

        if ([[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"seller_verification"] isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {

            cell.imgverification.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"verifiedIcon.png"];
            cell.lblverification.text=@"Verified";
        }
        else {

            cell.imgverification.image=nil;
            cell.lblverification.text=@"";
        }

            if([[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"favorite_id"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
            {
                cell.lblDeleteMyFavourite.text=@"";
            }
            else
            {
                for(NSString * string in self.arrayDynamicFavourite)
                {
                    if([string isEqualToString:[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"favorite_id"]])
                        cell.btnGreen.selected=YES;

                }

                cell.lblDeleteMyFavourite.text=[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"favorite_id"];
                //NSLog(@"%@",cell.lblDeleteMyFavourite.text);
            }

        //NSLog(@"%@",[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"watch_name"]);
        //NSLog(@"%@",[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"watch_price"]);

//        Favourite *cart=(Favourite *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Favourite" inManagedObjectContext:app.managedObjectContext];
//        
//        cart.favId=[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"id"];
//        [app saveContext];

        if([[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"watch_name"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        {
            if([[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"watch_price"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
            {
                cell.lblAdsTitle.text=@"NA";
                cell.lblprice.text=@"NA";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //NSLog(@"%@",[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"id"]);
            //NSLog(@"%@",[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"images_file"]);

            if([[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"iso"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
            {
                cell.imgLogo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Kuwait.svg.png"];
            }
            else
            {
                [cell showImage:arrayMyFavourite :indexPath.row];
            }

            NSString * imageURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@/%@",BaseURL,@"uploads/watch/",[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"id"],[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"images_file"]];

//            [cell.imgMain sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wachizLogoIcon.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
//             {
//             }];

            [cell.imgMain sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
                            placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wachizLogoIcon.png"]
                                     options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

            cell.lblAdsTitle.text=[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"watch_name"];
            cell.lblprice.text=[[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"watch_price"];

            [cell.btnISO setTitle:@"NS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            for (NSDictionary *dict in [[arrayMyFavourite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"features"]) {

                if ([[dict objectForKey:@"feature_name"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]&&[[dict objectForKey:@"feature_name"] isEqualToString:@"Currency"]) {

                    [cell.btnISO setTitle:[dict objectForKey:@"feature_value"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(indexPath.row%2==0)
            cell.imgCellBg.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        else
            cell.imgCellBg.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.91 blue:0.91 alpha:1.0];

    }
    else if (tableView==self.tableMySearch)
    {
        self.btnMyFavoriteDeleteCheckBox.hidden=YES;
        self.btnMySearchesDeleteCheckBox.hidden=NO;
        self.btnMyAdsDeleteCheckBox.hidden=YES;
        self.btnMyFavoriteDeleteAction.hidden=YES;
        self.btnMySearchesDeleteAction.hidden=NO;
        self.btnMyAdsDeleteAction.hidden=YES;

        cell.lblDeleteMySearch.text=[[arrayMySearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"];

        if(checkBoxTagValue==2)
        {
            //cell.btnSearchDeleteAction.selected=YES;
            cell.imgCheckbox.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"markedmw.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            //cell.btnSearchDeleteAction.selected=NO;
            cell.imgCheckbox.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"unmarkedmw.png"];
        }

        if([[[arrayNewMySearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"searchKey"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class] ] || [[[arrayNewMySearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"searchKey"] isEqualToString:@" "])
        {

            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            {
                cell.lblSearchTitle.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Bold" size:16];
                cell.lblSearchTitle.text=@"NA";
            }
            else
            {
                cell.lblSearchTitle.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Bold" size:14];
                cell.lblSearchTitle.text=@"NA";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(NSString * string in self.arrayDynamicSearch)
            {
                if([string isEqualToString:[[arrayMySearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"]])
                    cell.btnSearchDeleteAction.selected=YES;

            }

            cell.lblSearchTitle.text=[[arrayMySearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"favorites_name"];


            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            {
               cell.lblSearchTitle.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Bold" size:16];
            }
            else
            {
                cell.lblSearchTitle.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Bold" size:14];
            }
        }
        if(indexPath.row%2==0)
            cell.imgCellBg.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        else
            cell.imgCellBg.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.91 blue:0.91 alpha:1.0];
    }
    else if(tableView==self.tableMyAds)
    {
        self.btnMyFavoriteDeleteCheckBox.hidden=YES;
        self.btnMySearchesDeleteCheckBox.hidden=YES;
        self.btnMyAdsDeleteCheckBox.hidden=NO;
        self.btnMyFavoriteDeleteAction.hidden=YES;
        self.btnMySearchesDeleteAction.hidden=YES;
        self.btnMyAdsDeleteAction.hidden=NO;

        if ([[[arrayMyAds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"seller_verification"] isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {

            cell.imgverification.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"verifiedIcon.png"];
            cell.lblverification.text=@"Verified";
        }
        else {

            cell.imgverification.image=nil;
            cell.lblverification.text=@"";
        }

        cell.lblDeleteMyAds=[[arrayMyAds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"id"];

        if(checkBoxTagValue==3)
        {
            //cell.btnAdsDeleteAction.selected=YES;
            cell.imgCheckbox.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"markedmw.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            //cell.btnAdsDeleteAction.selected=NO;
            cell.imgCheckbox.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"unmarkedmw.png"];
        }
        cell.btnGreen.hidden=YES;
        cell.btnAdsDeleteAction.hidden=NO;

        if([[[arrayMyAds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"favorite_id"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        {
            cell.lblDeleteMyFavourite.text=@"";
        }
        else
        {
            for(NSString * string in self.arrayDynamicAds)
            {
                if([string isEqualToString:[[arrayMyAds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"id"]])
                    cell.btnAdsDeleteAction.selected=YES;

            }
            cell.lblDeleteMyFavourite.text=[[arrayMyAds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"favorite_id"];
        }

        if([[[arrayMyAds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"watch_name"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        {
            if([[[arrayMyAds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"watch_price"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
            {
                cell.lblAdsTitle.text=@"NA";
                cell.lblprice.text=@"NA";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if([[[arrayMyAds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"iso"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
            {
                cell.imgLogo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Kuwait.svg.png"];
            }
            else
            {
                [cell showImage:arrayMyAds :indexPath.row];
            }

            NSString * imageURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@/%@",BaseURL,@"uploads/watch/",[[arrayMyAds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"id"],[[arrayMyAds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"images_file"]];

//            [cell.imgMain sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wachizLogoIcon.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
//             {
//             }];

            [cell.imgMain sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
                            placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wachizLogoIcon.png"]
                                     options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

            cell.lblAdsTitle.text=[[arrayMyAds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"watch_name"];
            cell.lblprice.text=[[arrayMyAds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"watch_price"];

            [cell.btnISO setTitle:@"NS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            for (NSDictionary *dict in [[arrayMyAds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"features"]) {

                if ([[dict objectForKey:@"feature_name"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]&&[[dict objectForKey:@"feature_name"] isEqualToString:@"Currency"]) {

                    [cell.btnISO setTitle:[dict objectForKey:@"feature_value"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(indexPath.row%2==0)
            cell.imgCellBg.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        else
            cell.imgCellBg.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.91 blue:0.91 alpha:1.0];
    }

    cell.dp=self;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: see this link it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708812/uitableview-with-multiple-selection/33708924#33708924

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i have mentioned i don't wish to use UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark

Comment: dont think in `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` , in this place add your  "tick mark" button index thats all, if you not get the idea , just show your code I modify my answer

Comment: 1. create your own view and add it to accessory view..
2nd option--- play with button selected and unselected state

Comment: please do post a sample project

Comment: First Post your code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, What you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you with logic:

`UITableViewCell` as you said are reused every time you scroll up/down for a memory saving purpose.

What you can do is to save the states of all your cells in one model.

Let's say you have only one section in your `UITableView`:

Store in one `NSMutableArray` the states of your cells (checked/unchecked: `NSNumber` of `Bool` objects) , and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`you change you UIButton relatively to what you have in your array.

When your `UIButton` is pressed you change the value of the cell's state in your `NSMutableArray`.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

you find a working example [here](https://github.com/dingua/TableViewCheckTest)

The hole idea is that you keep your "checked" info stored in a Model because you can not rely on what UI gives to you and any time you show your cell you use your Model and you show the info that it gives.

Comment: Sounds great!! @mejdi Please help me with a sample code. +1 from my side

Comment: Thanks very much . But i am mising project file from your sample

Comment: hey @MejdiLassidi i followed your instruction but in my images are not changing. please help me, i already tried with button and image both are but not solved out